# Python. Instagram. Как поставить лайк?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

Я нашел функцию, которая проводит авторизацию в Instagram.

```
import requests, json, getpass

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"

token = ''

def authorization(USERNAME, PASSWD):
    BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
    LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'accounts/login/ajax/'

    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
    session.headers.update({'Referer': BASE_URL})

    req = session.get(BASE_URL)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
    login_data = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWD}
    login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
    token = login.cookies['csrftoken']
    login_text = json.loads(login.text)

    print(login_text, token, sep='\n')    


authorization('', '')
```

На вход функции надо просто подать логин и пароль, и пользователь будет авторизован. А как поставить лайк? Ссылка для лайка - "https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/{mediaId}/like/". Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать selenium `pip install selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver

def Like():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() # вместо Chrome можно написать другой браузер
    driver.get("ссылка для лайка")
    btn_like = driver.find_element_by_class_name( "wpO6b" )
    btn_like.click()
```

Comment: А существует ли возможность реализовать это при помощи запросов? Как и авторизацию

Comment: я хотел бы вступить в Ваш разговор... я пару раз писал о том, как "просмотреть в отладчике" обмен запросами между браузером и сайтом (например, здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321197/). То есть, в принципе сделать это можно. Но вот вопрос: зачем? просто вебдрайвер предоставляет Вам очень удобный интерфейс, через который Вы можете и авторизацию сделать :-)