# Хочу поймать все соединения к серверам (сайтам)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Хочу поймать все соединения даже ajax запросы. Чтобы потом сохрантить в файл. Как proxy, но не используя proxy. Возможно ли это.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотрите в сторону инструмента [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

Это такой "отладчик на стероидах" - в том числе, он показывает сессию браузера с конкретным сайтом, и позволяет довольно удобно посмотреть любой запрос.

Вот картинка, на которой видно что я смотрю тело пост - запроса к сайту, и смотрю этот запрос в виде json'а.

Обратите внимание, что для винды остаётяс бесплатным (не-триальным) так называемый fiddler classic. И что для установки фидделера и разрешения ему работать с https - соединениями нужно приложить некоторые усилия - но они себя оправдывают!

[image: fiddler picture]

Comment: Спасибо большое, познакомлюсь с программой.

Comment: Скачал настроил https. Но в список не превышается больше 100. Помеже подсказать где находится это настройка. Заметил у вас в списке 5990.

Comment: @BahodirBahodir - Я у себя посмотрел - не вижу никакого места, в котором кол-во captured пакетов ограничивалось бы 100 шт. И не помню, чтобы я это где то настраивал. Если вспомню или найду что то такое - напишу!

Comment: Извените оказывается всё работает. Я просто не зная нажал на кнопку Capturing.

Comment: @BahodirBahodir - Круто! Главное, что работает! А я уже стал искать видео, котрое посоветовать бы Вам посмотреть, чтобы понять, что идет не так. Можете, если Ваш вопрос таким образом решен, отметить мой ответ как "решение" - зеленая галочка рядом с ответом, кажется. При этом рейтинг растет и у меня, иу Вас