# Как получить html страницу как в отладчике браузера на c#?

Tags: c#, html, .net, парсер

Мне в некотором смысле нужно научиться править сайты, точнее один конкретный сайт и буквально 2 разных по сути страницы на нём. Как я понимаю api для него нету, поэтому я выбрал парсиг. Вот в отладчике браузера, когда я вижу эту разметку, Я даже знаю как оттуда вытащить нужные данные, однако если я в постмане провожу запрос, то мне выдаётся не эта верстка, а немного другой верстки и скрипт на JavaScript. JavaScript Я особо не изучал, но понимаю некоторые принципы, однако не особо вижу каких то конкретных запросов с нужными мне данными. Т.к. мне нужна такой html, как в отладчике браузера, а не этот html, который выдаётся по запросу, нужно его как то сконвертировать. Как это можно сделать?
P.s.: Я вообще не шарю за парсинг и это мой первый проект, кормиться Я этим не собираюсь, так что 10 000 часов учить парсинг тоже.

Comment: слишком абстрактный вопрос. Покажите какой html вам нужен, какой html загружается изначально, ссылку на сайт тоже было б неплохо указать тогда можно будет самому посмотреть как там что

Comment: Посмотрите вот эти вопрос-ответ, это практически полностью Ваш случай: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332570/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-requests-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python/1332585#1332585

Comment: Нужные данные приходят не в том ответе от сервера, в который вы смотрите, изучайте сетевой лог браузера (вкладка Сеть), данные скорее всего в другом ответе. Тот же JavaScript их не из воздуха берет, верно?